# Read Image Metadata with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, camera, metadata, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access metadata (exif tags) of image taken by UIImagePickerController - iOS/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991673/access-metadata-exif-tags-of-image-taken-by-uiimagepickercontroller-ios-iphon)

Is there a way to read the EXIF metadata of a picture taken by the iPhone camera. I'd like to be able to take a picture and read the picture's metadata immediately afterwords.
Any help is appreciated.
lq