# Detect where the image was taken (location) in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am working on a project which will ask the user to take an image from camera or photo library and then get the location of there the image was taken. I have used UIImagePickerController to get the image and I need know to detect the current location (if the image was taken from camera) or the location of where the image was taken (if the image was selected from the photo library)

can anyone help or guid me to a useful tutorial?

Cheers

Comment: Check this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991673/access-metadata-exif-tags-of-image-taken-by-uiimagepickercontroller-ios-ipho

Comment: http://jomnius.blogspot.ch/2011/01/what-is-inside-uiimagepickercontrollerm.html

Answer (score 4):

```
NSData* jpegData =  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pImage);

    CGImageSourceRef imageData= CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)jpegData, NULL);
    NSDictionary *metadata = (NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageData, 0, NULL);
```

This will deliver a dictionary with EXIF areas. The one you are interested in is the GPS data. You extact them using:

```
NSDictionary *exifGPSDictionary = [[[metadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary]mutableCopy]autorelease];
   // you don't have to autorelease when you use ARC
```

This exifGPSDictionary holds the values you are looking for with the keys `kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude` and `kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude`. And you fetch them using `objectForKey`.

Comment: Well, this solutions requires a certain version of iOS. If you need to be downward compatible for any reason then you may want to look at  http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/ .