# Is there way to get metadata of the image file in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimage, metadata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access metadata (exif tags) of image taken by UIImagePickerController - iOS/iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991673/access-metadata-exif-tags-of-image-taken-by-uiimagepickercontroller-ios-ipho)
>   [How to get image metadata in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478502/how-to-get-image-metadata-in-ios)

I have some image file in the iOS application local folder. 
How can i get it's metadata?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ImageIO Framework like explained in [QA1654](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1654/_index.html):

> To access the image properties you:
>
> 1. create a CGImageSourceRef for your image.
> 2. get a copy of the image properties dictionary by calling CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex.
> 3. access the values in the dictionary by calling CFDictionaryGetValue with the property key that you are interested in. The available keys
>      are located in the CGImageProperties Reference.

Comment: Of course, you should mention that you will have to add #import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h> to your header and the Framework in order to use the class..

Answer (score 2):

You can get its metadata with the `ImageIO` framework.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_intro/ikpg_intro.html