# Xamarin - Save photo from camera in 300dpi

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Scenario: Xamarin - Android - Visual Studio 2019

Hello!

I'm developing a android app to take photos of evidences.
The photo is captured and saved, but the saved photo is in 96dpi.

I need a 300dpi saved photo.
How convert a captured photo to from 96dpi to 300dpi?

Thanks :)

Comment: DPI is typically a print setting.  It doesn't have any bearing on the image itself.

Comment: If you check the data carefully, the photo should have all the pixels the camera is capable of. What are the width and height **in pixels** of the saved image? Of course it’s impossible to know for sure until you **show your code**.  What are you trying to do with the photo?

Comment: Understand that the dpi value set when the photo is taken is completely arbitrary. It has no effect on the quality of the stored image; but some number has to be put there, so the phone vendor picks a value. Later when the photo is used, the app that uses it should have options to control the desired print size. If you really wish to set this value, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35770510/199364. You’ll have to translate that java code into c#.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.