# How do I create a UIImage with the DPI set?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, core-graphics

I have a UIImage, and I wish to save it to Photos with the DPI metadata set. I understand that a UIImage is immutable, so I have to create a new UIImage. I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24785513/1037358) as a reference to create an swift extension function on UIImage that produces a new UIImage with the DPI set. I'm successfully saving this to Photos with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)`. I email this to myself (set as 'Actual Size') and open it in Preview but the DPI is always left at 72.

Here is the function that I converted:

```
func imageWithDPI(dpi :Int) -> UIImage? {
    guard let sourceImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 0.8) else {
        print("Couldn't make PNG Respresentation of UIImage")
        return nil
    }

    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(sourceImageData, nil) else {
        print("Couldn't create source with sourceImageData")
        return nil
    }

    var metadata = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) as? [String:AnyObject] ?? [String:AnyObject]()
    metadata[kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth as String] = dpi
    metadata[kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight as String] = dpi

    var exifDictionary = metadata[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary as String] as? [String:AnyObject] ?? [String:AnyObject]()
    exifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyTIFFXResolution as String] = dpi
    exifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyTIFFYResolution as String] = dpi
    metadata[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary as String] = exifDictionary

    var jfifDictionary = metadata[kCGImagePropertyJFIFDictionary as String] as? [String:AnyObject] ?? [String:AnyObject]()
    jfifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyJFIFXDensity as String] = dpi
    jfifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyJFIFYDensity as String] = dpi
    jfifDictionary[kCGImagePropertyJFIFVersion as String] = 1
    metadata[kCGImagePropertyJFIFDictionary as String] = jfifDictionary

    guard let uti = CGImageSourceGetType(source) else {
        print("Couldn't get type from source")
        return nil
    }

    let destinationImageData = NSMutableData()
    guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(destinationImageData, uti, 1, nil) else {
        print("Couldn't create destination with destinationImageData")
        return nil
    }

    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source,0, metadata)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)

    return UIImage(data: destinationImageData)
}
```

I'm kind of out of my depth in Core Graphics, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImage may be stripping all of the metadata from the image when you create it from the `destinationImageData`, including the DPI. I recently ran into this issue when sharing images via iOS’s `UIActivityItemProvider` API. If I returned a `UIImage *` from the `- (id)item` method then all metadata was lost. The fix was to return either an `NSData *` or an `NSURL *`.

Try returning the `destinationImageData` directly, or saving it to a file & emailing that to yourself.

I’m curious as to why you want to set the DPI for an image? DPI is mostly meaningless for nearly all digital images these days (unless an image is meant to exactly represent the dimensions of a physical object). Actual pixel resolution is far more important than DPI.

Comment: I'll give that a go when I get back to work tomorrow. The image is to be manually imported into a program that respects the DPI for printing later, so automating that step means it's one less manual task to do. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but if I save this raw data, how am I going to be able to load that into Preview or Photoshop to check the DPI?

Comment: You are correct. Using `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(...)`, `CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(...)` and `CGImageDestinationFinalize(...)` I could write the image to disk and the DPI is maintained! Thank you ever so much.

Comment: Glad that worked. Re: saving the “raw data”... The CFData/NSData representation would just be the equivalent of a JPEG file that had been read into memory (without decompressing it into an image). So you’d just save the CFData to a file & open that in Preview or Photoshop. Using `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(...)` is pretty much the exact equivalent of that process. You typically create a CFData destination if you’re going to transfer the file over the network or something similar.